# How to translate HiveQL query to corresponding DataFrame operation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my usecase, I was using hivecontext inside myRDD.map() function. I got error that java.lang nullpointerexception. I realized, it is not possible to use hiveContext inside the map logic. The hivecontext was used to fire a hiveql query to another table (conf). hiveContext.sql().  The query is like this

```
select config_date, filefilter, family, id from mydb.conf where     
id == 178 and config_date < cast("2011-02-04 13:05:41.0" as 
timestamp) and family == "drf" order by config_date desc limit 1
```

I have decided to create a dataframe of this table before the start of the map process in the driver code. And perform dataframe operations inside the map logic. Basically, want to do method calls over dataframe instead of using hivecontext to query.
Is it possible? Can someone help me out here how to replicate this query over dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, translating your Hive query to Dataset is perfectly possible.

You can just `spark.sql(yourQueryHere)` or rewrite the query to use Spark SQL's Dataset API.

Just load your Hie table using `spark.read.table("mydb.conf")` and do the filtering and ordering.

```
val conf = spark.
  read.
  table("mydb.conf").
  select("config_date", "filefilter", "family", "id").
  ... // you know the rest
```

You can then `join` this Dataset with the other and apply joined transformation that will will avoid using `hiveContext` inside map.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have a master hive table from which I created a dataframe. For every row of this table, a business logic is executed (inside the map). With some elements of a row as inputs, the business logic contact another hive table to retrive some more piece of information. I am not an spark expert. I created hivecontext.sql(<query>) but it failed. Then, i created a dataframe of another table and used inside the map process. Failed with the same error. What you are suggesting me is to use join both the datasets and perform joined transformation. Hmm.. I will try this.